# How to run Wordpress Blog on a Sub URI within a Rails App on Heroku

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, rack

I have a rails application that needs a blog. I have looked at various rails cms and blog engines and none of them meet my needs. I would like to add Wordpress on a sub uri www.example.com/blog. My application is hosted on Heroku. I am able to install wordpress independently as a separate app on heroku and I have tried adding wordpress to the public folder with an .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog.*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/-%2 -d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ -%2/$1 [QSA,L]
```

but to no avail. I cant use reverse proxies because I would like to have SSO (and shared navigation bar etc and really dont want wordpress and my app  to be "separate" applications on heroku) between the Rails app and the wordpress installation. Is there a way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [wordpress-heroku](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku)

As far as sub URI's, you start to make things more complex when it's not necessary. If you want you can run two Heroku apps, but instead of using folder paths, use a subdomain so your main app runs on www.example.com and your blog runs on blog.example.com. The use of subdomains is greatly respected in uses like this and makes things a lot easier.

Comment: you sound exactly like me when I was explaining this to the client. Cant really accept this as the answer though. I'd like for someone to either say its just not possible and explain why or provide a solution to the problem stated. Meanwhile, I am actively working on selling the alternate approach to the client. :) BTW wordpress-heroku is how I got Wordpress installed on Heroku in the first place.

Comment: Finally ended up convincing the client to use subdomains. Doesn't really answer the original question...but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to access the Virtual Host file for the server? If so then the adding the following in the server may be your answer:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
  ServerName ...
  DocumentRoot ...
  <Location /blog>
     PassengerEnabled off
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /blog/
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
     </IfModule>
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

However I guess it also depends on how the rails app is deployed and whether the public folder is updated on deployment. You may need to symlink the public folder so it is not updated each time the site is deployed.

I couldn't say if this would work for Heroku having never used their services but hopefully it will help.

Source: http://ziyedbd.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/deploying-wordpress-blog-inside-ruby-on-rails-application/

Symlink info: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/19/how-to-create-symlink/